# Bat file exits while execution

Tags: batch-file

I have the following bat file. It exits after module load ria/node.

```
@echo on
SET path =%PATH%; some path
SET MODULEPATH=SOME PATH
module load ria/node
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
ECHO ERROR 
) 
npm config set proxy some url
```

[image]

Comment: C recognises space. Put spaces in.

Comment: Where I need put space

Comment: Does it print any error message?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the errorlevel to see what it is set to? Maybe it just configures what it is supposed to do and then exits as usual. Also consider adding a `pause` at the end of your file and using the command line to debug it.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Do not use `pause`, just launch the file in an already opened Cmd window.

Comment: "and using the command line to debug it." @Melebius :) Addition: You should use `if errorlevel 1 ( echo error )` which means `if errorlevel >= 1`

Comment: Added image of full bat file

Comment: @kiranGopal Please paste the text directly into your question, so we can copy and try it!

Comment: @geisterfurz007 _“You should use `if errorlevel 1`”_ No, the errorlevel value might be negative with some programs. The OP’s variant should work. http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: `module load ria/node` to `module load ria /node`. Plus you have extra spaces in the line starting with `Set path`, remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `module load ria/node` use the command `CALL module load ria/node`.
Calling programs from a batch file quitter often needs `CALL` to make the batch file wait for them to exit.

Comment: You will probably have the same problem with `npm config set proxy some url`